# how to disable inter audio app in xcode

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my first app to the app store but the code gets rejected after uploading.
The email I'm getting reads as follows:
Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "iCard Counter". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported. Please check your Xcode project's code signing entitlements configuration, and remove any unneeded entitlements.

Specifically, key "inter-app-audio" is not supported.

Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

so how do I disable this illusive inter-app-audio in xcode.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section of Apple's iOS Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account) and then select your application identifier to view what entitlements are currently enabled.

For example, here's one of my apps:

[image: Edit Your App Profile]

If you click on "Edit", you can enable or disable various entitlements.

You *may* need to re-download updated provisioning profiles before resubmitting to the store.

Comment: thanks, everything was disabled, so I decided to go ahead and delete it and try and get a new one, maybe it'll help